# CSS specificity confusion

Tags: css, css-specificity

I have following markup:

```
<div class="breadcrumbs">
    <span id="links">
      <a href="/home.html" class="pointer">home</a>
      <span>&gt;</span>
      <a href="/module/users.html">users</a>
    </span>
</div>
```

My styles are defined like this:

```
.breadcrumbs{/*styles for breadcrumbs div*/}
.breadcrumbs span a{cursor:default/*other styles for breadcrumbs links*/}

a.pointer{cursor:pointer;}
```

On my page, the links show default cursor (arrow) and the style `a.pointer` is shown striked in IE10 console and firebug.

My confusion is that as `pointer` class is applied directly to anchor element, should not it override the one picked from `.breadcrumbs span a` match?

Comment: Check out http://specificity.keegan.st/, very useful to visualise specificity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, of course it shouldn't. The rule of specificity says that more specific the selector, the more precedence it will have. So in your case when you created a class that applies to all the anchor tags, and then another class which applies to anchor tags within a certain other html tag (div), then the second one will have a higher precedence because it's narrower in its targeting.

You could check out this great article from Smashing magazine to understand the rules of specifity. http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/

Comment: great definitely `breadcrumbs span a` is more specific or detailed than `a.pointer`.